# ios blocks with different parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

Iam completely new to ios Blocks and have no idea about the syntax .Iam trying to create a block which takes two parameter one an int and another a NSString and returns an int value. Iam getting error and don't know how to proceed help me with some tutorial or guide me through this is the block  .

```
    int (^indexFinder)(int , NSString *) =  int (^(int passedValue , NSString * passedText)       {};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
int (^indexFinder)(int , NSString *) =  ^(int a, NSString * b) {
    return 10 ;
} ;

int i = indexFinder(1, @"") ;
NSLog(@"%d", i) ;
```

I learn it from [Blocks programming topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

should be like this:

```
 int (^indexFinder)(int , NSString *) =  ^int (int passedValue , NSString * passedText)       {
    NSLog(@">> %d %@",passedValue,passedText);
    return 0;
 };

 indexFinder(0,@"hello");
```

here are some links that tackles about block: [link1](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/7/28/ios4-blocks-1), [link2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html)